# Using the response of AJAX Post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been developing a registration form and slowly but surely I have been learning some javascript and jquery along the way, to further support my knowledge of that and all. I have come across a problem however, the problem is I can't get the response from a AJAX request.

My AJAX request is in a separate function, I have multiple purposes for it. I have put alert();'s in the code for debugging purposes.

```
function validate_input ( input, type ) {
    $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: 'ajax_request.php',
            data: "type=" + type + "&input=" + input,
            success: function( response ) {
            if( response == "true" || response == "false" ) {
                alert( "working" );
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            } else {
                alert( "AJAX/jQuery Error" );
                alert( "Reponse !== true or false" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can confirm that the ajax_request.php file is echoing **true** or **false** correctly, however, for those interested here is the coding.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH') &&
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
exit('Direct Access to this file has been disabled.');

include('core/db.php');
$validateType = intval( $_POST['type'] );
$input = escape_string( $_POST['input'] );

if( $validateType == 1 ) // validate username
{
    echo ( user_exists( $input ) ? "true" : "false" );
} else if( $validateType == 2 ) // validate email
{ 
    echo "true"; // not coded yet
}
```

Finally, I call the function when it is necessary( *using .blur()* ), you can see below;

```
var username_value = "Jake"; // for debugging purposes, var definitely contains something
validate_input( username_value, 1 );
alert( validate_input( username_value, 1 ) ); alerts "undefined"
```

I am just wondering if anyone can see any issues with the code that would be causing this, and please don't suggest for me to use a validator plugin, that is not an answer to the question.

Thanks,

Comment: You are saying that it does echo true or false correctly. How do you know that? Also - have you checked in developer tools (F12 in all browsers, you may need to instal firebug on FF), network tab to see what is returned? Also - there is `error` event in jquery ajax, works like `success`. See if it is called when you do your request

Comment: Does your code only alerts "undefined" or does it also alerts for "AJAX/jQuery Error"?

Comment: Why don't you declare your data in the following way:

data: { type: bla, input: bleh }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, you can't return the response like that. Using ajax you define a callback function which is called when the response is received. Code execution does not stop and wait for the response before continuing.

So you need to do whatever you want to do within the success function, or call another function from there.

Comment: That would explain it, I never knew that. Is there a way I can change that, or would it simply be best to use $.post? Thanks

Comment: @JakeBall $.post will work the same as $.ajax except you don't need to declare type=post. You should just add the code to do what you want in the success function.

Comment: thank you for that, the reason I want/wanted to do it this way is I would like to validate both email and the username, and wanted to save writing excessive code and also keep my error activation code in the same place. Is there absolutely no way I can put the response of a ajax call into a variable for use later on in the script?

Comment: Of course you can store the response to a variable, just declare a variable in the global scope (outside of any function) e.g. `var storedResponse;`, then in your success function set it to the response e.g. `storedResponse = response;`.

Answer (score 1):

The ajax "type" is set to POST, yet your script is checking the $_GET array for parameters. Change $_GET to $_POST or ajax type to "get".

Comment: You've since edited your code so my answer doesn't make sense!

Comment: Sorry about that, I was changing those parameters and since left them as they were when the post was originally set, the script posts the data and my PHP script checks the $_POST variable

Comment: @rbaker you can delete your answer if it's no longer relevent.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert( validate_input( username_value, 1 ) ); 
alerts "undefined"
```

This will not work like that. First - you are using asynchronouse ajax call.

Second:

```
success: function( response ) {
            if( response == "true" || response == "false" ) {
                alert( "working" );
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            } else {
                alert( "AJAX/jQuery Error" );
                alert( "Reponse !== true or false" );
            }
        }
```

In code above return belogns to success  handler function, not to `validate_input` function. Basically, you return your response to nowhere.

So, instead of `return response;` you should do whatever you need to do with response:

```
success: function( response ) {
                if( response == "true" || response == "false" ) {
                    alert( "working" );
                    console.log(response);
                    alert(response);//here you do what you need.
                } else {
                    alert( "AJAX/jQuery Error" );
                    alert( "Reponse !== true or false" );
                }
            }
```

`.get`, `.post`, `.load` will work in the same way as they use `$.ajax` in behind